# How to inject EntityManager in non-EJB based WebService?

Tags: web-services, jboss, entitymanager, jbossws

The headline says it all: I've got a simple WebService

```
@WebService(serviceName="G08WService", portName="G08WPort", endpointInterface = "at.fhj.itm.g08.wservice.IUserWebService")

public class WService implements IUserWebService
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="g08b2")
    EntityManager em;

    @Resource 
    UserTransaction utx;

    public WService()
    {

    }
}
```

Of course the WebService is also defined in the web.xml, and calling the WSDL works just fine, a client can call webmeethods, and so on.

As you can see i want it to get the EntityManager and a UserTransaction to be injected, i need it to create a further DAO. However, both are always null.

The WebService is not EJB based, is there a way to retrieve those objects?

The Container is JBoss 5.0GA

Answer (score 0):

Because your webservice is not managed by the EJB Container, CDI is impossible. You should fetch the EntityManager manually by doing a JNDI lookup instead.

The EntityManager is not registered by default so you should add it in `persistence.xml`:

`<property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/yourEntityManagerName"/>`

or the factory:

`<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/yourEntityManagerFactoryName"/>`

Then perform JNDI lookup to obtain the container-managed entity manager:

```
 EntityManager em = (EntityManager) sessionContext.lookup("java:app/yourEntityManagerName");
```